# Which book or website do you recommend for self-learning calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I only know the basic formulas for differentiating and integrating. I want to learn calculus in detail. Which book or website do you recommend for it?

Comment: See [collegeboard](http://www.collegeboard.com/html/apcourseaudit/courses/calculus_textbook_list.html)

Comment: You will probably get many answers to your question. Try several of them and find a few that match your learning style.

Comment: Possible very duplicate: search this site for "recommend calculus" - or see this list of Related questions to the right.

Comment: Try Hardy's "A Course of Pure Mathematics".

Answer (score 0):

I taught using Stweart's [Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1285740629) for many years. The link I gave is to 8th edition which is obscenely expensive, but you can get [5th ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/053439339X) for under $10.

Answer (score 0):

One book comes to mind called Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus P. Thompson. It's available as a free ebook on [gutenberg.org](http://gutenberg.org). There is both a PDF version and a TeX version which can be found here:

> ## [Calculus Made Easy](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283)
>
> #### By: Silvanus P. Thompson
>
> Being a very-simplest introduction to those beautiful
> methods which are generally called by the terrifying names
> of the Differentia